# Framework for Trello-Like Drag&Drop "Stories" Application in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trello

for learning purposes, I want to build an application in RoR that allows users to upload their "stories", and with through drag & drop get the stories on different lists (or boards), like widgets on a dashboard. The final objective is something very similar to Trello.

Could you please recommend a framework, gem, tutorial or starting point suited for this learning endeavour?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The application you are describing is divided in two almost seperate areas where you might look for gems, but most functionality can actually be standard Rails.

For Drag & Drop Sorting you might have a look at [these (jQuery) plugins](http://www.knight.io/categories/drag-drop-sorting-nesting-js).

Feel free to ask a specific question if you hit any problems along the way.